# SQL fixed vs floating point literals

Tags: sql, database, floating-point, fixed-point

Is there a standard in SQL as to whether a number typed in as something like the following will be fixed or floating point?

```
SELECT 1.2 + 7.8
```

In a programming language, I am so used to fractional numbers being represented as FP, and usually having to import a separate library (if its not included in stdlib) to work with decimals. But in SQL, it seems that there are variations in how it's sometimes represented, for example in postgres `1.1` would default to NUMERIC whereas in BigQuery `1.1` would default to FP. Is there a standard or guideline on how decimal-numbers should be treated in SQL, or it's entirely up to the implementation. And if the latter, is there a consensum on what's the better approach?

Comment: In Oracle database this would be type of Number

Comment: @alexherm is `Number` fixed or floating point?